# Blank screen when opening MyMonero

Tags: mymonero

I'm using MyMonero and when I open my client up and type in the password, a blank screen comes up.

I have tried restarting the  computer, restarting the client, I don't know my 13 / 25 code to just connect via monero.com or whatever. I have all my files and stuff, is there any way to get my wallet working or get my coins? I use MyMonero client via PC by the way.

Comment: Have you already contacted MyMonero's support directly through email?